Not possible to use containers in Azure Pipelines self-hosted agents deployed as Azure K8s pods
We are planning to move away from an autoscaled Azure VMSS to an Azure Kubernetes Cluster for hosting our self-hosted Azure DevOps Pipeline build agents.
I have now setup my first small test cluster and I am running some test pipelines. In these pipelines I am using the container feature of Azure pipelines to run jobs in dedicated container.
But as it seems this is not supported when using AKS since I am getting an error message (during "Initialize containers" step) that "docker" is not accessible/installed when running the pipeline.
Is this a limitation that I have to accept? This would mean I cannot use AKS for my self-hosted agents and pipelines. Or is there some workaround possible to make it work?
Thank you

Yes, using containers in Azure Pipelines self-hosted agents deployed as Azure Kubernetes pods is not supported due to the Docker-in-Docker restriction on AKS 1.19 or later. However, you can still use AKS for your self-hosted agents and pipelines by running your jobs in dedicated containers outside of the AKS cluster. One workaround is to use Azure Container Instances to run your container jobs. You can configure your pipeline to use ACI as a deployment target for your container jobs.

Another option is to use self-hosted runners in a Container Apps job, which allows your workflow to access resources inside the job's virtual network that aren't accessible to a cloud-hosted runner.


Run a self-hosted agent in Docker - Use Azure Kubernetes Service cluster
Run a self-hosted agent in Docker - Azure DevOps Services | Azure DevOps Server 2022 - Azure DevOps Server 2019



Tutorial: Deploy self-hosted CI/CD runners and agents with Azure Container Apps jobs (container-apps-jobs-self-hosted-ci-cd-azure-pipelines)


It doesn't support nested containers. According to this official doc,

When you specify a container in your pipeline, the agent will first fetch and start the container. Then, each step of the job will run inside the container. You can't have nested containers. Containers aren't supported when an agent is already running inside a container.

